# Interactive iPhone mirroring using touchscreen

Tags: iphone, interactive, touchscreen

is there any way to mirror and use an iPhone with a touch monitor?
I need to create an app demo presentation.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you got solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPhone screen sharing can only be done by Airplay.

There are many softwares that is used to screen-share from iPhone to Mac/Desktop

http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/

http://www.x-mirage.com/x-mirage/

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. do those two software allow to control the iphone using the touch monitor instead?

Comment: you cant control your iphone device in another device only you can touch it in iphone

Answer (score 0):

[AirServer](http://airserver.com) is probably the best for this, it supports both Airplay and Miracast for projection of smartphone to screen. It allows you to record the screen to file as well as stream live on YouTube, with webcam and everything.